# Why doesn't logistic regression pull the predictions to the mean?

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression

Below is the toy example (a logistic regression with 2 categorical predictors)

```
set.seed(1)
y=round(runif(150))
x1 = round(runif(150)+.2)
cat = c(rep(1,30), rep(2,70), rep(3,50))
cat = factor(cat)
x2 = model.matrix(~cat)[,2:3]
data = data.frame(cbind(x1,x2,y))
logistic = glm(y~x1 + cat2 + cat3, data=data,family = "binomial")
preds = predict(logistic, data,type="response")
data$predictions = preds

> # Global mean
> mean(data$y)
[1] 0.4933333
> # Prediction
> mean(data$predictions[data$x1==1 & data$cat2==1 & data$cat3 == 0])
[1] 0.4433128
> # Group mean
> mean(data$y[data$x1==1 & data$cat2==1 & data$cat3 == 0])
[1] 0.4489796
```

I thought the prediction should be pulled closer to the global mean by the intercept compared to the group mean but it is not the case here. Intuitively, the reason I think so is because here we use data from all groups to build 1 model instead of separate models for each group. Therefore the predictions will be influenced by all observations across all groups and I feel like that influence should make the predictions closer to the global mean.

I think my understanding is wrong. Really appreciate any help.

Comment: The partial pooling I described is only for random effects models.  The predictions are pooled to the global mean *as compared to the dummy variable example*.  Logistic regression does not always pool predictions closer to the group mean.

Comment: this may be a very basic question but I feel like intuitively it should right? Otherwise I wonder what the role of the intercept here?

Comment: You'll have to explain your position in your question.  I can't see why you would think that.  If you edit your question, I can reply.

Comment: edited, hopefully it is clearer